# Why JLabel is not visible at mine JFrame class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to learn java,but I met some problems where finding answers is not so simply for me.
Task I wanna do seems to be quite simply.

I wanna add a label to Frame. MyFrame is a JFrame class with some basics modyfications like size, color etc.

**Main code looks like this:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // a GUI window to add components
        MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
    
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Images/background.png");
        //a GUI display area for a string of text,image or both
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Why it is happening?",image,JLabel.CENTER);
        myFrame.add(label);
        //label.setText("Why it is happening?");// set text of label
        //label.setIcon(image);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        
    }

}
```

And the result I get is this which I want:
[correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77c5V.png)

When I comment last line about label it is changing appearance of mine UI. It is displaying only JFrame without my label at all.

**Not working code:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // a GUI window to add components
        MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
    
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Images/background.png");
        //a GUI display area for a string of text,image or both
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Why it is happening?",image,JLabel.CENTER);
        myFrame.add(label);
        //label.setText("Why it is happening?");// set text of label
        //label.setIcon(image);
        //Commented
        //label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        
    }

}
```

Here is graphic result:
[not working label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juLhY.png)

Did I miss some basics information ?
I think both should work the same.

Comment: Add components to a Frame before packing and showing that Frame.

Comment: I was wondering if it is just order of the commands, but I saw code like this(and it was working):   frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(label):
   
That is why I was confused. Before I had issue with File.exists so I thought it is another error coming from java.
   
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one. At first glance I agreed with @VGR. But then if it is all down to the order of painting etc. - then I would have expected a call to 'repaint()' or even 'invalidate()' to fix the problem. Doesn't seem like it... so perhaps this is a bug in swing.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // a GUI window to add components
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Images/background.png");

        myFrame.setSize(500,250);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Why it is happening?", image, JLabel.CENTER);
        myFrame.add(label);

        //label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER); 
        label.repaint(); //Should have the same effect as the line above, but doesn't!

        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: *then I would have expected a call to 'repaint()' or even 'invalidate()' to fix the problem* -  The issue is that by default Swing components have a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. When you pack or make the frame visible the layout managers are invoked and components are given a size/location so they can be painted properly. Invoking repaint doesn't affect the size/location so there is still nothing to paint. Also, don't use invalidate(). In Swing you use `revalidate()` to suggest that a property of the component may have changed which may cause the size/location to change.